# Access 2016 - linking reports to different tables

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access and am using Access 2016. I have created a few tables and am trying to create some reports. At the moment I have a Customer table which includes a Customer ID - this links to a 'Volunteers' table which simply creates a new Volunteer ID and holds the Customer ID which links to the 'Customer' table. I also have an 'Events' table. Both the 'Events' table and 'Volunteer' table link to a 'Volunteer by events' table - holding the Events ID and Volunteer ID. I want to create a report based on the 'Volunteer by events' table - but instead of showing the Events ID and Volunteer ID I want it to show the Event Name (linking back to the events table) and the Volunteer Name (linking back to the Customer table via the Volunteer table). The existing fields pane only show the tables directly linked to the 'Volunteer by Events' table. I'd be really grateful for any help on this. I realise there will be some kind of join in here but have no idea how to do this is Access.

Comment: Use the query designer to build a query with all tables and fields you need.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I've done that and it works perfectly! Sorry for taking so long to reply - I now have time to carry on with this work and have more questions. Look out!